# CSS tag selector Query

Tags: css

I have this code on my page

```
<div id="secondary">
<ul id="news">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Virgo: It's Your Month</span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Dolor site amet </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now to change the color of the text and links I use this css style

```
#secondary * {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

This changes everything inside to white.

Why cannot I add color: #FFF to an existing style like this?

```
#secondary  {
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #294E56;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Why doesn't this work? As far as I know, the color is inherited by the tags within the secondary ID. Thanks and Regards :)

Comment: What's `#secondary`? I don't see such an ID in your HTML.

Comment: I've made the correction. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 3):

The anchor tag does not inherit a number of CSS properties, including 'color'. When you add the * to the selector, it explicitly selects all tags under #secondary and applies the style, whereas without *, you're just relying on inheritance, which won't work in this case. What you need to do is

```
#sidebar a { color: #FFF; }
```